# creating message box as sheets for mac in PyQt

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

I used message box as seperate dialog instead of sheets for mac OS, now i m working on it to spawn a sheet as message box instead of seperate one.

I have tried setting the message box as a modal one:

```
(messagebox.setWindowModality(QtCore.Qt.WindowModal))
```

and setting message box, parent dialog window flags as sheet

```
(parentDialog.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.Sheet) messagebox.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.Sheet))
```

But the above commands are not working to create a sheet instead of seperate dialog.

Does anyone have an idea of how to solve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A dialog cannot be shown as a sheet with `exec_()`.

Instead, simply use [QMessageBox.open()](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qmessagebox.html#open), which, on a Mac, is roughly equivalent to:

```
messagebox.finished.connect(self.handler)
messagebox.setWindowModality(QtCore.Qt.WindowModal)
messagebox.setParent(messagebox.parentWidget(), QtCore.Qt.Sheet)
messagebox.setResult(0)
messagebox.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the Assistant you only need to set the window modality and the parent. Do you set the message box' parent to the parent dialog?