# QFileDialog sheets

Tags: macos, qt, qt5, qfiledialog

Is it possible to display `QFileDialog::getSaveFileName()` as a sheet on Mac OS?

Setting the parent widget does not seem to help, I'm using Qt5.

Edit: @troyane suggest something along the lines:

```
QFileDialog dialog(this);
dialog.setWindowModality(Qt::WindowModal);
dialog.setResult(0);
dialog.show();
```

but it crashes... I must be doing something wrong, though not sure what exactly...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

- Create your own `QFileDialog` without using the static functions. For more information see [official documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qfiledialog.html#details).
- Then follow instructions from here https://stackoverflow.com/a/8244876/867349 (there is Python code, but probably, that would be not a problem to understand and replay it in Qt).

Hope, this will help!

Comment: Thanks! I tried what you described but maybe I misunderstood some parts of it as the program crashes from time to time, please see the edit above. Also, I tried slightly different method but there seems to be a bug in Qt, I filed it here: https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-30119